# Localization via resx doesn't work for non-specific resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-localization

I'm banging my head against a wall here and wonder if anyone has gone through this.

I have localization working on an ASP.NET Core MVC application, via resx, if I use a specific culture (in my case, `es-ES`).

I have a `Resources\Localization.es-ES.resx` file, with a dummy `Localization` class (for shared translation resources) and it works when the culture is `es-ES`. Now I want that file to work for all `es` cases, so I thought just renaming it to `Localization.es.resx` should do, but that's not picked at all.

My configuration is:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
  opts =>
  {
      var supportedCultures = new[]
      {
          new CultureInfo("en-US"),
          new CultureInfo("en"),
          new CultureInfo("es-ES"),
          new CultureInfo("es"),
      };
      opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
      opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
      opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
  });

/* ... */

services.AddMvc()
      .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
```

And:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

I'm injecting an `IStringLocalizer<Localization>` and using it to translate. The query string (`?culture=es` or `?culture=es-ES`) which I use for testing) gets picked up correctly, and again: **this all works when I'm using the specific es-ES culture in the resources filename**, it just doesn't when I switch to a non-specific one (just `es`).

This is all important because this app is specifically going to be used on other `es-??` cultures and I don't want to have a copied resource file for each.

The docs specifically say (at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

> Imagine your site receives a request for a "Welcome" resource using culture "fr-CA". The localization system looks for the following resources, in order, and selects the first match:
>
> Welcome.fr-CA.resx
>
> Welcome.fr.resx
>
> Welcome.resx (if the NeutralResourcesLanguage is "fr-CA")

This fallback behavior doesn't seem to be working for me. Maybe I'm missing some configuration?

Comment: Maybe [this is related](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/293), though it sounds like a fix may have been released so I don't know why it would still be an issue. Your issue may be unrelated, I guess?

Comment: @john I don't think so... that seems to be a problem if your default culture is not english, but mine is... and the fallback to show the keys instead of the translation if none is found seems to be working. Just the "es-XX" to "es" before isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, the problem was that I didn't have the "generic" in the supported cultures.  In my case adding "es" did the trick.

```
var localizeOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
            .SetDefaultCulture("en-US")
            .AddSupportedCultures("en-US","es-MX","es")
            .AddSupportedUICultures("en-US", "es-MX","es");          
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizeOptions);
```

Comment: Note sure about this (although the question is pretty old and I'm not using it anymore, or maybe it has been fixed), but I had in my code `opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");` which should be akin to `SetDefaultCulture()` and `new CultureInfo("es")`, on the array (which should be the same as your fluent configuration is doing on `AddSupportedCultures()`)

Comment: But again, this was 2018, it's probably been fixed (if it was a bug) by now, so we'll never know :-)

Comment: I see - I didn't really read your code carefully enough to see that you were essentially doing the same thing.